# Google One-Tap Sign In / YOLO project status

Tags: google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

we are trying to enable the One Tap sign-up from Google. It seems there was some security concern (reading online not officially by google) and the official document has been taken out by Google.

Is that API still working, can we integrate it or should we wait for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find related functionality in Smart Lock for Passwords section [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth)

Looks like original SDK was removed in favor of more common browser Credentials Management API ([draft of w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/credential-management/)) in [Сhrome 51](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api) and then reworked in [Chrome 60](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/credential-management-updates).

Also, they have a [codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/credential-management-api/index.html?index=..%2F..index#8) to learn it step by step.

Comment: Hi @alexsey,  tried the one tap login URl as: 

<div id="g_id_onload" 
data-client_id="SOMETHING" 
data-login_uri="https://cellbell.in/wp-login.php?loginSocial=google&redirect=https://cellbell.in/my-account"">
</div>

RESULT: Login happens, but when I visit again on homepage, it again shows login pop up. Not sure how to handle it.

Can you please help?

Google Docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap